# anguarl 1.63 ui-router 1.0 Local transition hook like effect

Tags: angularjs

I have need of a *local* transition hook event. For example

When *controller A* is instantiated I want all transitions from state *foo* to state *foo.bar* to be logged. When I look at [Transition api](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/docs/latest/modules/transition.html) , the UI routers abilit is on for *global* transition hooks. I want to achieve a transition hook locally, I want that hook destroyed when the controller is destroyed.

The answer doesnt have to be a transition hook, it can be anything that gets destroyed when the controller is destroyed.

I have tried every variation method on *$transition* service, to no avail. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add a plnkr link or some code snippet?

Comment: add a plunkr to show that Transition Api works globally and cant work locally?

Comment: have you tried to create hook in controller onInit and destroy it onDestroy?

Comment: No i have not. That is a good idea.

Comment: @PetrAveryanov that worked, and it achieved want I wanted. Thank you very much. If you mark that as the answer I will award you the upvote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 controller: ["$scope", "$transitions", function ($scope, $transitions) {
            this.$onInit = function() {
                $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'Home.*' },
                    function(transition) {

                        console.log('foo');
                    });
                $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'Home.*.*' },
                    function(transition) {

                        console.log('bar');
                    });
            };

            this.$onDestroy = function() {
                $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'Home.*' }, undefined);
                $transitions.onSuccess({ to: 'Home.*.*' }, undefined);

            }



        }]
```

I ended up using the onInit, onDestroy for controllers. This way my hooks were destroyed after I was done with them.